# Calling an inner function in Python

Tags: python, etl

I have this final main.py that combines every function I wrote separately, but I can't make it work, it actually returns the Success at the end but it actually does nothing nor in my local folders or MongoDB. The function is this one:

```
def gw2_etl(url):

    def log_scrape(url):
        HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'}

        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=HEADERS)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        data = soup.find_all('script')[8]
        dataString = data.text.rstrip()

        logData = re.findall(r'{.*}', dataString)

        try:
            urlLines = url.split('/')
            if len(urlLines) < 5:
                bossName = urlLines[3]
            elif len(urlLines) == 5:
                bossName = urlLines[4]
        except Exception as e:
            return 'Error' + str(e)
        
        tag = bossName.split('_')
        bossTag = tag[1]

        try:
            # Wing_1
            if bossTag == 'vg':
                pathName = 'ETL\EXTRACT_00\Web Scraping\Boss_data\Wing_1\Valley_Guardian'
            
        with open(f'{pathName}\{bossName}.json', 'w') as f:
            for line in logData:
                jsonFile = f.write(line)
                return jsonFile

        return log_scrape()
    
    def store_data(jsonFile):

        with open(jsonFile) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        
        sp = jsonFile.split('\\')
        posSp = sp[-1]

        bossTag = posSp.split('_')
        nameTag = bossTag[1]


        if len(bossTag) > 2:
            nameTag = bossTag[1]
        elif len(bossTag) == 2:
            tagSplit = nameTag.split('.')
            nameTag = tagSplit[0]
        
        # Players Data:
        player_group = []
        player_acc = []
        player_names = []
        player_classes = []

        for player in data['players']:
            player_group.append(player['group'])
            player_acc.append(player['acc'])
            player_names.append(player['name'])
            player_classes.append(player['profession'])
        
        try:
            # Wing-1
            if nameTag == 'vg':
                # Create lists:
                player_dps1 = []
                player_dps2 = []
                player_dps3 = []

                # Phase_1
                phase1 = data['phases'][1]['dpsStats']

                phase1_time_raw = data['phases'][1]['duration']
                phase1_time = round(phase1_time_raw/1000,1)

                for dps in phase1:
                    dps1_raw = dps[0]
                    player_dps1.append(round(dps1_raw/phase1_time,2))

                # Phase_2
                phase2 = data['phases'][6]['dpsStats']

                phase2_time_raw = data['phases'][6]['duration']
                phase2_time = round(phase2_time_raw/1000,1)

                for dps in phase2:
                    dps2_raw = dps[0]
                    player_dps2.append(round(dps2_raw/phase2_time,2))

                # Phase_3
                phase3 = data['phases'][12]['dpsStats']

                phase3_time_raw = data['phases'][12]['duration']
                phase3_time = round(phase3_time_raw/1000,1)

                for dps in phase3:
                    dps3_raw = dps[0]
                    player_dps3.append(round(dps3_raw/phase3_time,2))

                stats_dict = {
                    'players':{
                        'group': player_group,
                        'account': player_acc,
                        'names': player_names,
                        'profession': player_classes,
                        'phase_1_dps': player_dps1,
                        'phase_2_dps': player_dps2,
                        'phase_3_dps': player_dps3
                    }
                }

                df = pd.DataFrame(stats_dict['players'], columns=['group','account','names','profession','phase_1_dps','phase_2_dps','phase_3_dps'])
        
                return stats_dict

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error' + str(e))
            sys.exit()
            
        # JSON generator (MongoDB)
        pathName = 'ETL\TRANSFORM_01\Players_info'

        jsonString = json.dumps(stats_dict)
        with open(f"{pathName}\{nameTag}_player_stats.json", 'w') as f:
            f.write(jsonString)
        
        # CSV generator (MySQL, PostgreSQL)
        
        df.to_csv(f"{pathName}\{nameTag}_player_stats.csv",index=True)

        return store_data()
    
    def mongo_connect(stats_dict):
        try:
            client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Connection could not be done' + str(e))
            sys.exit()

        db = client['GW2_SRS']
        collection = db['players_info']

        mongo_insert = collection.insert_one(stats_dict)
        return mongo_connect()

    return 'Success!'
pass
```

My goal is that, when I call gw2_etl(), it runs every process inside (log_scrape, store_data and mongo_connect) and returns the Success message at the end. I'm probably doing it wrong since it neither runs anything nor send an error message.

For the mongo connection, I need to return the stats_dict, since it is the JSON file that I want to upload there, csv file is just for local storage.

I actually got some bosses out since the code it's actually pretty long.

If you have any hint or clue about how could I make this work, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: I suggest you find a way to ask your question that does not require 600 lines of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to call all of those functions separately from within the `gw2_etl()` before returning from the function. Defining [functions inside another](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) just means you can't access them outside of the outer function. So before the return statement add

```
log_scraper(url)
store_data(json_file)
mongo_connect(stats_dict)
```

and continue from there. You'll notice that you need to carry over some variables to invoke the functions with the correct arguments, but I left that part for you to figure out.